# How can I solve these connection-issues with pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql

We have in our local network a server with a Postgres-Installation. Now, as some big inserts (needed days) were running, others had problems connecting via pgadmin. After opening the Server in pgadmin (that would showing the tables in the overview) pgadmin was trying and trying, without progress. As I understand that the inserts can slow down access to the same database, it shouldn't prevent them at all, am I right? So what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say the server is running out of RAM and swapping heavily, so it's not servicing requests properly. It may also explain why the inserts are taking so long.

Can you ssh into the server?

Does `top` show significant swap use?

There isn't really enough info in the question to really say, beyond pointing you in that direction.

Comment: No swapping, enough free RAM. Stuff besides Postgres worked well and the sysem reacted fluent.

Comment: @Mnementh so ... big checkpoints + slow storage? Check the PostgreSQL logs, enable checkpoint logging.

Comment: Hmm, slow storage... We save the DB on a Linux-Software-RAID 1. Can that be slower?

Comment: If it's on a pair of 5400 or 7200rpm SATA/SAS disks, then yes, it's likely pretty slow and prone to severe I/O bottlenecks and stalls under load. You really want SSDs or a proper RAID controller with a battery backup unit. You can reduce stalling on slow I/O devices by spreading checkpoints, increasing wal segment sizes, and lowering Linux's dirty write thresholds. Lots of info -> google on that.

Comment: Oh, and enable checkpoint logging.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the insert will actually slow down the connection significally.

what you could try : renice and ionice the backend pid with the insert statement.
Depending how you start the sql you might be able to directly use the "script" with lower IO prio.

Comment: So it is indeed the insert blocking the other SQL-requests? Hmm, bad luck for us then.

Comment: Unlikely. Insert doesn't block select/update/delete.

Comment: Well, but without the Inserts,the selects run good.

Comment: it doesn't technically block them, but still makes a lot of IO resulting in slowing down other processes, which in term might timeout other processes.